# Soundcloud api "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'uri' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, soundcloud

I have been calling soundcloud player in my website based on genre. However, sometimes it's returning "Cannot read property 'uri' of undefined" and sometimes it isn't. Any idea why looking at my code?

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">

      <a href="javascript:;" class="genre" style="width: 100%; float:left;">
        <div class="card trance" data-genre="trance">
          <div class="overlay-card" style="display: table;">
            <span><h2>Trance</h2></span>
          </div>

        </div>
      </a>

      </div>
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">

      <a href="javascript:;" class="genre" style="width: 100%; float:left;">
        <div class="card techno" data-genre="techno">
          <div class="overlay-card" style="display: table;">
            <span><h2>Techno</h2></span>
          </div>

        </div>
      </a>

      </div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">

      <a href="javascript:;" class="genre" style="width: 100%; float:left;">
        <div class="card metal" data-genre="metal">
          <div class="overlay-card" style="display: table;">
            <span><h2>Metal</h2></span>
          </div>

        </div>
      </a>

      </div>
```

Click action function

```
$('.genre').click(function(){
    if($(this).find('.card').attr('data-genre').length > 0){
      playSound($(this).find('.card').attr('data-genre'));
      $('#results').html('<img src="assets/image/spinner.gif" class="loader">').show();
      $('#loader').css({'display': 'none'});
    }else{
      console.log('length 0');
    }
  });
```

Sound playing function

```
function playSound(genre){
  SC.get('/tracks', 
  {
    genres: $.trim(genre),
    order: 'hotness',
    // q: '*',
    bpm: {
      from: 100
    },
    limit: 50
  }, function(tracks){
      var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 49);
      console.log(genre);  /* It is always returning true */
       SC.oEmbed(tracks[random].uri, {auto_play: true, maxheight: 240, show_comments: true }, document.getElementById('results'));
        $('.genre-playing h3').html(genre.toUpperCase());
        $('.genre-playing').css({'display': 'block'});
  }); 
}
```

To check, what's the issue is, I `console.log(genre)` inside `playSound()`. It is always returning the genre I clicked. Then what can be the issue here?

Comment: Have you checked the value of random against the length of the array of tracks? console.log them both and see what values they have when you get the error.

Comment: Log `tracks[random]` in console and check.

Comment: A safer random number would be `var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * tracks.length)`

Comment: Bravo. Never thought about that. So I have to write a recursive function now.

Comment: 'random' value may acceeds the tracks.length

Comment: @nickborti Why do you think you would need to write a *recursive function*?

Comment: @Phil Actually I don't need to. You are right. Heat of the moment I wrote that. :D

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, `SC.get` can return anywhere between 0 and `limit` tracks so your random number should not exceed the actual number of tracks.

Say your search only returned 10 results and your random number was 40 (between 0 and 49), attempting to access `tracks[40].uri` would fail due to an out-of-bounds error.

Use this instead

```
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * tracks.length);
```